# Facebook não permite a apresentação de posts em iFrames?

Tags: html5, facebook

Segue uma rotina que busca todos os posts de um determinado usuário via `Facebook Graph API`, apresenta o horário que foi postado e a mensagem, descrição e o tipo de post numa `DIV`:

```
FB.api(
    {
        method: 'fql.query',
        locale: 'pt_BR',
        query: 'SELECT post_id, source_id, message, created_time, type, description, permalink FROM stream WHERE source_id = ' + friend_data[i].id + ' LIMIT 50'
    },
    function(posts){
        if(posts.length>0){
            var divFriendsPost = document.getElementById('friend' + posts[0].source_id);
            var friendPosts = '';
            for(var j=0; j < posts.length ; j++) {
                var d = new Date(0);
                d.setUTCSeconds(posts[j].created_time);
                dateFormat = [d.getDate(), (d.getMonth()+1), d.getFullYear()].join('/');
                timeFormat = [d.getHours(), d.getMinutes(), d.getSeconds()].join(':');
                if(posts[j].permalink != null && posts[j].permalink != '') {
                    friendPosts += '<a href="' + posts[j].permalink + '" target="_blank">';
                }
                friendPosts += '<div class="singlePost">';
                friendPosts += '<div class="spLeft">';
                friendPosts += '<p>' + dateFormat + '</p>';
                friendPosts += '<p>' + timeFormat + '</p>';
                friendPosts += '</div>';
                friendPosts += '<div class="spRight">';
                friendPosts += '<p>' + posts[j].message  + '(' + posts[j].type + ')</p>';
                friendPosts += '<p>' + posts[j].description +'</p>';
                friendPosts += '</div>';
                friendPosts += '</div>';
                if(posts[j].permalink != null && posts[j].permalink != '') {
                    friendPosts += '<div>';
                    friendPosts += '<iframe height="400" src="' + posts[j].permalink + '"></iframe>';
                    friendPosts += '</div>';
                    friendPosts += '</a>';
                }
            }
            var newNode = document.createElement('div');
            newNode.innerHTML = friendPosts;
            divFriendsPost.appendChild(newNode);
        }
    }
);
```

O problema é que não basta apresentar estas informações na DIV, pois na maioria das vezes o post é um compartilhamento ou publicação de fotos, por exemplo.

Tive a ideia de colocar o link (permalink) num `iframe` sob a DIV, mas o console retorna o seguinte erro:

> Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/...' in a frame because
>   it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

Eu acredito que o facebook bloqueie este tipo de ação.

Como resolver este problema, ou seja, simplesmente mostrar somente o post (sem nada que o cerca na página do facebook) sob a DIV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não precisa criar um iFrame com o post do Facebook. Você pode usar o [Facebook Embedded Posts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts/).

Ele cria automaticamente um iFrame com o post que você deseja. Basta passar o link.

[image: Facebook Embedded Posts]

Answer (score 2):

Isso ocorre porque ao acessar o HTML da página, tem o seguinte header

```
x-frame-options:DENY
```

Isso explicitamente diz para o navegador que não quer que o site seja visto dentro de um Iframe. É comum fazer isso para obrigar as pessoas a acessarem o site pela URL do site, e não pela url de outros e, claro, **por questões de segurança**, e evitar, por exemplo, que seja fácil roubar senhas ao tentar fazer a pessoa pensar que ela realmente está no Facebook.

A solução para você resolver isso é usar a API oficial do Facebook. Eles já disponibilizam botões de likes, comentários e afins. Isso que você está fazendo, aliás, se não for via uma API própria, é explicitamente proibido nos termos de uso do Facebook.

Comment: É proibido mostrar um post numa página própria ou é proibido mostrar o link num iframe?

Comment: Simplificando: com exceção das páginas que já existem na API, como botões e comentários, nenhuma página do Facebook abre em um iframe.

Comment: Carregar qualquer url de facebook.com que não seja uma API via Iframe é proibido. Visite https://developers.facebook.com/ e veja tudo que eles autorizam e até facilitam pra você fazer

Comment: Eu acho que ele só quer pegar os textos dos posts e exibir, mas eu não entendi direito a dúvida, também.

Comment: Sim, _é proibido_. Fazer algo que vai contra os termos de uso do facebook, se detectado, pode bloquear seu acesso e todas as contas que você usa. E pode levar a cadeia em casos mais extremos. Exemplo foi um desenvolvedor que fez um crawler que adicionava pessoas  e foi a publico admitindo isso e só não foi preso porque ele já tinha ajudado a descobrir falhas de segurança antes.

Comment: Felipe, eu possuo inúmeros perfis e fan pages que controlo o conteúdo. Entrar uma a uma dá um trabalho gigantesco. Por isso, estou fazendo esta aplicação para mostrar todos os posts por ordem de data. Existe alguma outra forma de se fazer isso?

Comment: Alexandre isso que está pedindo e outra pergunta. Não faça ela aqui, crie um tópico novo